# How to update some part of text using SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query saved in column of a table named `sqlcode` which is maintaining the metadata. For instance following is a query:

```
select 
    id, name, address, phone,
    .......
    ......
    , upddate 
from 
    bank a
join 
    bankreg b on a.id = b.id 
where 
    (condition)
```

I'm trying to update the text of query saved in metadata but I want to only update column names part of the query without making any change to select, from, joins or any other conditions. Any way of only updating column names would be helpful. I've tried using `replace` function but couldn't got desired output.

I want to update columns of this textual query with the columns present in  master table. If new columns are added in master, I want to add them to metadata query as well which is saved in text form. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` gives me the column names now I just want to update these column names to above query

Comment: I left my crystal ball at home today. Could you possibly provide some details so we can help? What are you trying to do? What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: Can you not rebuild the entire statement each time by using the data in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ? This may be easier than using replace.

Comment: How are we suppose to help you if that's all you have?????  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the columns you need to update in brackets, you can update them in your REPLACE, without updating the items in the SELECT portion.

```
select 
id,name,address,phone,
.......
......
,upddate 
from bank a
join bankreg b 
on 
a.id = b.id 
where ([address] = 'My Street')
```

Your update would then be:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyCol = REPLACE(MyCol , '[address]', '[some_other_field]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanna rename names of columns in select part?

Use `currentNAme AS NewName,` or `currentName NewName,` for each name you wanna rename.

Depends on the DBMS weather one or other or both syntax are supported (sql-server -> go with AS). Test with 1 column name to see which one works then use that one till end

```
select 
id AS myNameForId,
name AS myNmeForName,
.......
......
,upddate 
from bank AS a
join bankreg AS b 
on 
a.id = b.id 
where (condition)
```

OR

```
select 
id myNameForId,
name myNmeForName,
.......
......
,upddate 
from bank a
join bankreg b 
on 
a.id = b.id 
where (condition)
```

Comment: I want to entirely replace all columns with a set of new columns which are saved in a variable as `nvarchar`

Comment: You can't replace columns with the ones that don't exist in a result of your query.  Think of that part like filter, which columns from list of available (when you do all joins below) you wanna select. You can rename those or keep original names you cant add columns from somewhere else as you please.